# Замена содержимого всей страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть страница html. Через jQuery я отправляю запрос скрипту, мне нужно чтобы ответ сервера заменил собой содержимое страницы.
Пробовал через $('html').html=answer; но не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уважаемый, да вам нужно для начала доки почитать: [html(значение)](http://jquery-docs.ru/Attributes/html/#val)

> Добавляет код HTML для каждого совпавшего элемента. С документами XML использовать данный метод нельзя, но можно использовать с документами XHTML.

А уж если код нужен, то:

```
$("body").html(answer);
```

Comment: У меня страница index.htm
<!DOCTYPE....
<html><head>Тут head</head><body>Тут body</body</html>
из этой страницы выполняется скрипт, который получает ответ такой же структуры, как и сама страница. Мне нужно заменить содержимое

Comment: @TAPAHbl4 ну так Вы пробовали вместо "body" подставить "html"?) Экспериментируйте!

Comment: спасибо, исправил)
из-за моей тупости.
вместо $('body').html(data); писал $('body').html=data; :D

Comment: можно было так написать: $('body')[0].innerHTML = data; То есть вы выбираете первый элемент из полученного списка $('body') и нативным js изменяем код.

Comment: Сейчас начал смотреть, неправильно работают скрипты. Глянуть исходный код - полностью новые head и body запиханы в старый body :(

Comment: Вместо body пробовали html подставить?

Comment: Ну а с какой радости им правильно работать если вместо всего содержимого ты заменяешь только body ?
<pre><code>$('html').html( answer );</code></pre>